# random normal numbers using 2d means vector

Tags: python, numpy, normal-distribution

I have a vector of 2d means.

```
means = np.array([[0,0], [0, 3], [3,0], [3,3], [0, 5]])
```

I want to generate random normal numbers using this means vector.
If the means were only in x axis, I would do this in a way like this:

```
x_samples = np.asarray(list(map(lambda mean: np.random.normal(mean, 1), x_means)))
```

Is there a simple way to generate the samples for x and y together?
Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With two mean values (x and y) for each point, I am assuming you want a multivariate normal distribution with these mean values in each axis, and standard deviation of 1 in each axis? (The standard deviation is 1 in your 1d example)

in which case you can use [np.random.multivariate_normal](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/random/generated/numpy.random.multivariate_normal.html).

```
xy_samples = np.asarray([np.random.multivariate_normal(mean, np.diag([1., 1.])) for mean in means])
```

or similar to your formulation, using map:

```
xy_samples = np.asarray(list(map(lambda mean: np.random.multivariate_normal(mean, np.diag([1., 1.])), means)))
```

the `np.diag` deals with the fact that you need to supply a covariance matrix, not scalar variance.